# WPF Extended Toolkit DropDownButton

Tags: wpf, xaml, dropdown

I'm using Extended WPF Toolkit.

How can I change standard style of arrow in this DropDownButton?

```
    <wpfx:DropDownButton
        Width="200"
        Height="32"
        Content="DropDownButton: ClickMe">
        <wpfx:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
            <wpfx:WrapPanel Background="Aqua">
                <StackPanel Width="100" Height="100">
                    <Button>Click Me</Button>
                </StackPanel>
            </wpfx:WrapPanel>
        </wpfx:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
    </wpfx:DropDownButton>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to modify the (entire) control template. You will find the default one here: https://github.com/xceedsoftware/wpftoolkit/blob/015d89f201800a275feacf8eccedfd58fb1a59ca/ExtendedWPFToolkitSolution/Src/Xceed.Wpf.Toolkit/DropDownButton/Themes/Generic.xaml

You could copy it to your project and set the `Template` property of your `DropDownButton`:

```
<wpfx:DropDownButton Width="200" Height="32" Content="DropDownButton: ClickMe">
    <wpfx:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
        <wpfx:WrapPanel Background="Aqua">
            <StackPanel Width="100" Height="100">
                <Button>Click Me</Button>
            </StackPanel>
        </wpfx:WrapPanel>
    </wpfx:DropDownButton.DropDownContent>
    <wpfx:DropDownButton.Template>
        <!-- add the ControlTemplate here -->
    </wpfx:DropDownButton.Template>
</wpfx:DropDownButton>
```

Look for the `Path` with an `x:Name` of "Arrow" in the template. You need to set the `Data` property of this to the `Geometry` that represents the arrow you want.

There is "Arrow" property or something that you simply can set to some enumeration value or similar. You need to define the look of the arrow yourself and modify the template.